# How to make background over video tag?

Tags: css, html

I tried to make background over video tag with opacity 0.6:

**html:**

```
<body>
   <video></video>
</body>
```

**Css:**

```
body {
   background: #000;
opacity: 0.6;
position: relative
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question a little bit more? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[check out this fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/omvaity/yx0j003c/)

```
    .video-wrapper{width:320px;height:240px;position:relative;}
    .video-overlay{background:red;opacity:0.6;position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;}
    .video-wrapper:hover .video-overlay{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
body {}
video {
  position: relative;}
video:after {
  content: '';
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```